# What is the degree and number of terms of $n^2+n+1$?

Tags: polynomials

How many terms does  $n^2+n+1$  have ? two or three?

Of course we can factorize it and get  $n(n+1)+1$  , but can we call $n(n+1)$ a monomial?

If yes then $n^2+n+1$ has two terms and the degree is $1$ and if no then it has three terms and the degree is $2$.

what is the answer?

Comment: $n(n+1)$ is not a monomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Number of terms" is a *syntactic* measure, hence may differe among *algebraically* equal expressions. To make it less syntactic, we can speak (for expressions that are polynomials in a given set of variables) of the number of nonzero monomials that polynomial has; that would make $n^2+n+1$ (and also $n(n+1)+1$!) have three monomials , the highest being of gegree $2$, hence the whole poynomial is of degree $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition of a term,

A term is a product of a variable and a constant.

A monomial is an algebraic expression with only one term.

We cant consider $n(n+1)$ as a monomial sice it is a product of a variable and variable.

So we have 3 monomials :-).

Answer (score 0):

The number of terms is dependend on how you factorize. Usually you the number of 'top level' summands is called the number of terms, so we have two terms in $n(n+1)+1$ but you have three terms in $n^2+n+1$. The *degree* on the other hand is always the same: It is the *greatest* exponent of *n* (if you expand everything). A monomial in $n$ is usually a term of the form $c n^k$.

But if you do not have an explicit polynomial, the number of terms is usually the number of terms in it's fully expanded form.

Comment: If you insist that each of the terms is a monomial, then the number of terms is well defined isn't it?

Comment: Yes ususally it is, but I am not sure when you consider quotients of polynomial rings.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in other answers, there are three monomial terms. The interesting transformation in this light is to set $m=n+\frac 12$ when you have $$n^2+n+1=m^2+\frac 34$$

This kind of transformation (known as "completing the square") reduces the number of terms to two, and is fundamental to analysing and understanding quadratic expressions (ones having degree two).